# pip3 not point to new version after make install python3.8

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a old ubuntu so apt install python3.8 will not work. system default python is 3.5.

Then I build python3.8 successfully and run sudo make install. but when I try pip3 install package-name, it still point to python3.5.

I know use python3.8 -m pip install package-name works but I would like to change pip3 to point to new python version directly.

Is it's possible, please help direct me how to do it!

Comment: Try using "pip3.8 install ..." instead of "pip3 install". It works for me but in windows OS

Comment: I have seen enough cases where people have had to reinstall whole OS because of messed up dependencies installing new versions of python. You can try installing pip with `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` or what i would do is something like `alias pip3="python3.8 -m pip"`